# SP 2013 Workflows stopped working in my workflow manager farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, workflow-manager-farm

I have a Server Farm consisting of 1 WFE and 1 Sql Server. I have configured about 20 SP D 2013 complex workflows in this farm with the help of workflow manager CU2 refresh.
 Twice in a week, i used to restart these servers at night as part of maintenance activity.

Yesterday when i did the restart of these servers-first my WFE and then SQL Server - all of my SP D workflows **STOPPED** working.
and I am stuck with why my workflows have not started? I have restarted the `sp admin service`, `sp timer service`, `service bus gateway service` from my WFE's services console.But still the workflows are not starting.

What might have went wrong?

1. Should I do something on the SQL server side?
2. Should I restart/stop some other services from WFE?
3. Should I re-configure my workflow manager again ? This is a bit risky thing! :-(

Suggestions please!

Comment: What could've changed at the servers since the last restart. Have e.g. Windows Updates been applied to the servers recently? If so, which? Do you have backups which you can restore to a temporary VM and explore the findings, or do comparison? Does your ULSLogs record fails concerning WFs? Are there errors/alerts at CA? Have you confirmed the time synchronization matches between the servers?

Comment: Additionally, [this just briefly handled question](https://serverfault.com/questions/855238/find-out-who-disabled-a-windows-service) on another network made me think whether you could see changes on the services of your WFE - which of them were possibly restarted, stopped, etc. around the time of restarts. If there were unexpected actions of some services, I'd restart them as well.

Comment: on the servers, we have applied APRIL 2017 CU for the SP 2013. Since its not an windows updates.am not sure whether this will affect  these services or not. Please correct me here. I have not checked the ULS logs. Regarding the Errors /alerts in CA, NO, i am not seeing any errors alerts in CA. Regarding the "time synchronization matches" can you please elaborate, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Would like to know, other than the mentioned services, is there any extra services I need to take care while restarting these servers/services? please throw some light on this!

Comment: I couldn't keep it in the length of a comment, so answered below. Regarding the services, I don't see a reason to restart anything besides you have mentioned, unless they have had recent unexpected actions as detailed earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of these should be taken a look at before going into SQL side, not to mention re-configuring anything:

**Always** the question nr. 1, when a behavior differs since the last time: What could've changed at the servers since the last restart?

- Have e.g. Windows Updates been applied to the servers recently?

  - If so, which?
- Does your ULSLogs record fails concerning WFs?

  - If yes, what is found? To where it leads to?
- Are there errors/alerts at CA?

  - If yes, are they new since the errors appeared?
  - Each concerning the issue, and each recently appeared alert should be taken a look at
- Have you confirmed the time synchronization matches between the servers?

  - For how to, see e.g. [1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2655727/sharepoint-all-servers-in-the-farm-should-be-in-the-same-time-zone), [2](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Check-server-time-for-all-76fdd4c0)
- Are there recent actions done for related services?

  - To see when and by who actions might have been done/triggered, see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/855238/find-out-who-disabled-a-windows-service)
- Do you have backups which you can restore to a temporary VM and explore the findings, or do comparison?

As you mentioned about a recent update, applying a CU should ring an alarm if that has been done between the last restarts. If the CU's installation wasn't finalized, it might cause some services or features not to work correctly (such as workflows). Also any other Windows Updates within the same time interval should be looked at in detail. Many things can be discovered, and it wouldn't be the first time an update causes unexpected issues which should be rollbacked and waited for further fixes.

Comment: that was very detailed explanation of the causes of mys topping of my services. That will definitely help me in identifying the root cause of my issue. Thanks!